# \AtBeginEnvironment not accepting parameters in the code

Tags: environments, etoolbox, hooks

[etoolbox's docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) say in the section on environment hooks:

> Parameter characters in the code argument are permissible and need not
>   be doubled.

However, this won't compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{foo}[1]{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{foo}{begin hook: #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}{bar}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

The error message is

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
\@begin@foo@hook ->begin hook: ##
                                 1
l.11 \begin{foo}
                {bar}
```

Am I doing something wrong or the docs are mistaken?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is referring to a case such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{foo}[1]{}{}
\AtBeginEnvironment{foo}{\newcommand\baz[1]{begin hook: #1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}{bar}
  \baz{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

where we don't need to double the `#` tokens in the definition of `\baz`. That's in contrast with say

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\foo[1]{%
  \newcommand\baz[1]{begin hook: ##1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{foo}{bar}
  \baz{Lorem} ipsum dolor sit amet.
\end{foo}

\end{document}
```

where we do need to double `#` tokens.

The hook *cannot* access `#1` for the environment any more than any other code can (it does not add to the underlying `\foo` but rather uses a dedicated macro). As such, if you want to access `#1` you *have* to redefine `\foo` (or the equivalent `\renewenviornment{foo}`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! How obvious. It seems that I have spent too much time in normal programming languages recently, where you call functions instead of expanding macros... ;-) (Well, you *do* expand macros in Lisp, but I haven't used them very often recently).